# JS+React Object not conserved in value attribute of <option> tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have a drop down list that is fetched from an online DB, and loops through the list, `allStaff` as follows:

```
      <select onChange={handleChange}  className="select-css">    
                <option disabled  defaultValue selected>Select Name</option>

                {allStaff.map(person=>(
                    <option value={person} key={person._id}>{person.name}</option>
                ))}
      </select>
```

My `handleChange` function sets my stateless state, person, as follows:

```
const handleChange = event => {
    person = event.target.value;
}
```

So when I try to extract parts of person it seems to register as a string equal to `[object Object]`, which I've checked through console logging, e.g. I'll try `person.name` and will get an error. What have I missed out the stops me from writing person as the person object?
for reference, `allStaff` comes in correctly as:

```
[
  {
  "_id": "5ec63e97516541c07c2b26d3",
  "name": "Bob the builder",
  "clockedIn": false
 },
 {
  "_id": "5ec68b41307f0b002436234a",
  "name": "Bobby turner",
  "clockedIn": false,
  "time": "1333"
 },
 {
  "_id": "5ec68b4d307f0b002436234b",
  "name": "Bobby timer",
  "clockedIn": true
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option's value should be a string,

```
<select onChange={handleChange}  className="select-css">    
            <option disabled  defaultValue selected>Select Name</option>

            {allStaff.map(person=>(
                <option value={person._id} key={person._id}>{person.name}</option>
            ))}
  </select>
```

Then in your handleChange you should have something like that :

```
const handleChange = event => {
   personId = event.target.value;
   person = allStaff.find(staff=>staff._id === personId)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing basically this but with looping through allStaff to match the specific one. Some reason thought it would be possible just to hold onto that object when it was clicked. Makes sense, ty!